# ERC20 approve() not working in Remix

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20

In Remix, I have a `Depository` smart contract that is supposed to escrow user funds. My first step is to call `token.approve` with the address of the deployed `Depository` and amount, but I'm not getting the expected behavior.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.5.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Token is ERC20 {}

contract Depository {
    function transferFrom(uint amount) external {
        Token token = Token(0xFab46E002BbF0b4509813474841E0716E6730136);
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    }
}

contract Owner {
    function transfer(uint amount) external {
        Token token = Token(0xFab46E002BbF0b4509813474841E0716E6730136);
        // 0xF5c73... is the address of the deployed Depository contract
        token.approve(0xF5c7313cB994A0F8cEee341dC61C15753F775Fcf, amount);

        // Now that Depository is approved to spend amount tokens, instruct it to transferFrom
        Depository depository = Depository(0xF5c7313cB994A0F8cEee341dC61C15753F775Fcf);
        depository.transferFrom(amount);

    }
}
```

`Owner.transfer`'s `token.approve` doesn't seem to behave. I'm calling it from an address with 10000 ERC20 tokens and passing 50 as the `amount` argument. When I invoke `transfer`, two things happen:

1. I get the alert: `Gas estimated failed. Gas estimated errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? The execution failed due to an exception. Reverted`
2. After clicking `Send Transaction` anyway, I'm presented with the following Metamask window, which isn't the expected `approve` transaction.

[image]

[image]

I'm new to Solidity, and pretty darn stumped. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you check the transaction receipt from when your `Owner` contract calls `transferFrom` on your `Depository` contract? does it exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm calling it from an address with 10000 ERC20 tokens

You need to have the tokens in the Owner contract. As the owner contract is the one that is calling `approve`.

The failure is happening because there aren't enough ERC20 tokens in the Owner contract. Transfer 50 to that from your user wallet and then call the function.

Answer (score 0):

I gave Tirtha credit, because his answer is correct and the one that helped me. I'd just like to piggyback on his answer to elaborate a bit more.

The reason why Metamask wasn't presenting me with an "approve" transaction is because `Owner` is the one invoking `approve`, not my selected Remix account. I'm only calling `Owner.transfer`, which *then* tells `Owner` to call `approve`, but I'm not directly invoking `approve` myself.